# Can I get the position of dragged element in lwc

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am trying to implement drag and drop in lightning web component with a bit nicer animation, which means I want to be able to see some animation when the dragged item is hovering over some other elements.

I searched and experimented around for a while. In JQuery, we have methods like $(ele).getOffset() to get the in time position. And reactJs we have the hover hook. But I am not quite sure in lwc if there is anything I can use in this case (which can be vanilla javascript).

I have also tried the following code:

```
itemDrag() {
    let card = this.template.querySelector("div.draggable");
    let rect = card.getBoundingClientRect();
    console.log(rect.top, rect.right, rect.bottom, rect.left);
}
```

itemDrag is triggered based on ondrag event. However, also it got fired many times, the rect position remains as the starting point which potentially means I can't rely on getBoundingClientRect() in this case.

Any suggestions?